# Make the same list available to diferent users with hierarchy OOB

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I have a list which has all the information stored of everyone in the organisation.

Now, i want to create a view for all the nodes in the hierarchy in the organisation such that the line manager will be able to view his/her reportees status and

this continues till the CEO. For example, in the diagram below:

[image: org chart]

Now, if a manager sitting in the LOB1 visits the view, he should see the records of Program1, Program2, Program3 but not from the programs of LOB2 or LOB3. People from all the LOBs are entering information, but the view will only display hte relevant details.

If we create a Lookup column and depending on the Assigned To column gets back all the managers inline and fetches into the column so that when we create a view, we can use a filter for that column and equals [me] for displaying relevant information. The problem here is that we have  a list for looking up the information. Could you please help me with an idea or a logic for displaying the results.

Tnx

Comment: how many are the lob's?

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar situation (well, without CEO and only three levels). I can't remember all the details right now- I'm at home.

First, we created a list that holds the LOB, Program,Project info. The fields were:

```
   Name: LOB1, LOB2,project1 etc (unique!!!!)
   S/N : serial number (unique)
   Father's serial number (-1 for CEO)
   SP group : SP group that inside are the users who can update the certain type of item.
```

The list had 90 items

So, when an item was inserted, the permission were given bottom to top. In your example, project1, program1, LOB1, CEO .
Feel free to ask for any clarifications